# Node.js _http_server.js' Server function's first line confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading node.js' http modules' source code. In `_http_server.js` it has a function

```
function Server(requestListener) {
  if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(requestListener);
  net.Server.call(this, { allowHalfOpen: true });

  if (requestListener) {
    this.on('request', requestListener);
  }
  ...
}
```

I can't understand the first line `if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(requestListener);`.

In other files for example the function `http.createServer`, this function is called as `return new Server(requestListener)`. Because the object that `new` create is never an instance of `Server` function. Won't it be an infinite recursive loop?

---

Answers below are great. But here is a little complement to my confusion:

By calling `new Foo()`, a new `object` will be created. Then `object`'s `[[prototype]]` will be linked to `Foo`'s `.prototype`. Only after that `this` will be bound to `object` and `Foo` will be executed.

Since `instanceof` check whether `Foo`'s `prototype` is in `object`'s prototype chain, if `Server` is called by `new` then the newly created `object` will be `Server`'s instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common idiom to allow instantiation of a class without having to use `new`. In other words, it allows both of these:

```
let instance = new Server();
let instance = Server();
```

That first line is meant to catch the second method of instantiating (which is just a regular function call). In that case, `this` doesn't refer to the new instance, so `this instanceof Server` will be false.

When that happens, an instance is creating using `new Server()`. The same function will be called again, but because of using `new` the `this` variable will now point to the newly created instance and the check bypassed (so it doesn't create a recursive call).

> In other files for example the function `http.createServer`, this function is called as `return new Server(requestListener)`. Because the object that `new` create is never an instance of `Server` function.

It's an instance of the `Server` *class*.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an element with `new`, the object created is the instance of the function referenced as `new`, so when `http.createServer` calls `return new Server(requestListener)` then the `new` element **is** an instance of `Server`.

This way is impossible to have a loop because when is not an instance, it creates a new instance, being this way:

- I'm called, let's check if I'm an instance of me
- Nope, create a new instance of me
- I'm called, let's check if I'm an instance of me
- Yep, I'm an instance of me. Move on

This is done to create a new instance of `Server` without the need to call `new`.

```
var serverinstance = Server(rqlistener);
var serverinstance2 = new Server(rqlistener);
```

Both are an instance of `Server`, because of the inner code of the `Server` function.

Under my opinion, I don't like these kind of hacks btw.